# Is Shadow Admins Really a risk factor in Active Directory?

Tags: windows, active-directory, identity-management

From my understanding shadow admin is,A user account becomes a shadow admin if it has strong privileges over an existing admin account.
Similarly, any other account with strong privileges over the shadow admin’s, also becomes a shadow admin.
if SDProps overwrites All Admins account's permission, then how Shadow admin Risk is possible?

Shadow admin refrences:

https://www.cyberark.com/resources/threat-research-blog/shadow-admins-the-stealthy-accounts-that-you-should-fear-the-most

https://www.silverfort.com/blog/the-hidden-dangers-of-shadow-admins/

Example:
Bob is  a member of domain Admins Group.Alice is  normal domain user.
Alice Has reset Password Permission Over Bob's Account.
This means that Alice can reset Bob’s password, then login as Bob and execute tasks that require Domain Admin privileges.
This makes Alice a level 1 shadow admin.
Now Larry is a another normal domain user.
Larry Has reset Password Permission Over Alice's Account.
This means that Larry can reset Alice’s password, login as Alice, change Bob’s password, then login as Bob and execute tasks that require Domain Admin privileges.
This makes Larry a level 2 shadow admin.

From Microsoft Document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/security-best-practices/appendix-c--protected-accounts-and-groups-in-active-directory),
SDProp is a process that runs every 60 minutes (by default) on the domain controller that holds the domain's PDC Emulator (PDCE).
SDProp compares the permissions on the domain's AdminSDHolder object with the permissions on the protected accounts and groups in the domain.
If the permissions on any of the protected accounts and groups do not match the permissions on the AdminSDHolder object, SDProp resets the permissions on the protected accounts and groups to match those configured for the domain's AdminSDHolder object

Now if SDProps resets the permissions of Bob’s account to match the AdminSDHolder Object Permissions, is there a possibility for shadow admin's existence in an AD environment?

Comment: I am not aware of any definition of "shadow admin" that matches yours. It is definitely a risk having an account that is supposed to be less privileged exercising control over an account with greater privileges, but this isn't a huge problem and can be mitigated, as you note. "Shadow Admin", though, refers to accounts that are privileged outside the normal means, such as admin group membership. They are shadow because they are harder to find and track, and easily forgotten. So, I disagree with your fundamental definition of the term you're trying to understand better.

Comment: Shadow Admin accounts ARE bad, but the type of account setup you're describing isn't as bad, and it isn't "shadow admin".

Answer (score 1):

By default, the user that installs Active Directory is already made domain admin, the highest form of admin, and unless you do something specific to create lower tier admins (you need to do more than just create a user, you need to add group policy or set specific rights on the user), other admin users are equal to the main admin, and they can edit each other and themselves.

It becomes a lot more difficult if you actually want to take away privileges, and as long as you have an account on the domain controller that is admin, you can always revert back the change.

If you don't trust someone with admin access, you can setup admin access but limit their access or modify rights.